# alarm does not show up

Tags: android, alarm

im trying to set a testalarm when i click on a button inside one of my fragments. but the alarm dosent show up.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(context, "OnReceive alarm test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

//Button is inside a Fragment
Button SetAlarmButton = (Button)(v.findViewById(R.id.SetAlarmButton));       
        SetAlarmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try{
                    Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();

                    alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
                    alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
                    long alarmMillis = alarm.getTimeInMillis();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(view.getContext(), 192837, intent, 
                                                              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(view.getContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
                    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmMillis , pendingIntent);

                }catch(Throwable e){AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                    e.printStackTrace(pw);
                    sw.toString();  
                    builder.setMessage(sw.toString());
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
        }});
```

i know that i need to modify my manifest and add something like this but i dont know how and where exactly

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">
            ....
        </receiver>
```

to my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
    package="com.test.alarm" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/> 
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_main" android:name=".Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".First_Start"
        />    
        <activity
            android:name=".Preferences"
            android:label="Settings">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for AlarmManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

The Alarm that you're setting isn't related to the Alarm Clock functionality built in to the Clock application.

Alarms are used by the system to allow the application to respond to some event in the future. You basically tell the system you want your app to be woken up in some amount of time, and you define what Activity gets called when the Alarm goes off.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm");
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hours);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, mins);
startActivity(i);
```

but with this i cant specify the day i want the alarm to be set

Comment: Doesn't look like setting the day of the week pattern is possible with the AlarmClock intent. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html